# Strong security precautions for an Android app to prevent it from being cracked

Tags: android, security

Can you suggest me any good anti-crack approaches (other than a code obfuscation), considering that the paid apps on the Market are easily cracked, and the same goes for a basic server check after a PayPal transaction?

My idea is to have one (very important for the app) Java object saved on the server, and passed to the app each time when it starts. Do you think that this sounds good ?

Note that it is more like of a theoretical question, as I am not going to implement it in an app, I am more like seeking the knowledge for this rather than a concrete solution to a problem.

Any ideas would be appreciated, even ones that you are not very sure if they are good or not. Remember, the question is for Android apps. Thanks.

EDIT: I know that there can't be an unbreakable client side application, I am asking for a good option to prevent it other than a obfuscation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Code stored on the server and provided for execution on the device can be grabbed and stored elsewhere such as locally.  (And that's probably going to be as hard for you to implement as it will be for the attacker to patch around)

Ultimately, you have to face the fact that preventing run authorization just isn't possible on a general purpose computing platform.

Unless you move actual functionality to execution on a server requiring an individually authorized account, all you can hope for with regard to code running on the user owned device is to achieve a higher than average shade of difficulty.

Comment: I'm gonna agree. Use LVL & obfuscation, and anything beyond that is time you should spend making your app better, increasing value for your paying customers, and increasing appeal to prospective customers.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - you mean that they can grab it with a reflection and store it ?

Comment: @Blumer It is more of a "theoretical" question, I am not even sure if theoretical questions should be posted on StackOverflow, but still. I am not going to waste time on this instead of improving the app.

Comment: Reflection is not needed to grab it - just figuring out what the app is doing and faking that, or patching a copy to record what it downloads or using a patched or rooted platform to copy the temporary download elsewhere.  Reflection might or might not be involved in running it in your original application - it's going to be awkward to run downloaded code anyway, and probably pretty trivial to alter what you come up with to run a saved copy of the code stored elsewhere.  The fundamental technical issue is that a general purpose computer ultimately does the posessors bidding, not yours.

Comment: @Chris Stratton "doing and faking that" - I am talking about an object for the whole calculations before each frame in a game for example, faking that is the same as if they do the game on their own, which is fine by me. "record what it downloads" - I am talking about using SSL of course, after all it is a security question. "awkward to run downloaded code" - I don't think it is, just getting the bytes and using them (with an interface for the object of course).

Comment: By downloaded code onto the device into run-able form, you put it where (at least with a rooted phone) it's trivial to make a copy of the decrypted download.  Going through the rather convoluted process of invoking downloaded code provides a simply place to patch to substitute the copied download instead.  But reimplementation is an important point - the best you can hope is to make the cost of cracking your app greater than paying some offshore code factory to produce a fully legal and legitimate work alike alternative to compete with yours in the open market.

Comment: I doubt that there is such a thing as "cost of cracking your app" as the result of the crack is just a free version of the app, and therefore nobody is going to gain something if he pays money to somebody to crack it. My original question was if this is going to be hard enough, and not if it is going to be impossible to break or not. Anyway, you answered that it is not going to be that hard, so thanks.

Comment: Actually there is a monetary benefit to investing (a little) in the cracking of apps - there are subscription based websites offering hundreds of cracked apps.  Not legally (at least in first-world countries) but then that doesn't seem to be a huge impediment to their business model.  Requiring just a bit more investment to crack than others would keep you off those sites until someone decided figuring out how to crack your app was worth it.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - I never thought about this, you are right and I should have thought about it before saying to you that you are not right and there isn't such thing. I voted you up.

Comment: No problem - in a way I've told you two almost contradictory things - that you can't ultimately secure it, but you can secure it enough that they'll go bother other people instead, at least for the moment.  And being original in your methods will give you some protection from bulk attacks, since they'll actually have to think about your app specifically.  Just be sure that your methods don't annoy legitimate users to the point where they crack it to improve usability rather than to pirate it.